# Rearrange an array alternating positives & negatives in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I need to rearrange an array with bubble sorting method so that positive and negatives numbers are alternated but I don't know how to continue it. I've just managed to put all positive numbers at the beginning and the negatives at the end. 
Any ideas?
Thank you very much in advance!

E.g. 
input= {1,3,-4,5,9,-3,-7} // output= {1,-4,3,-3,5,-7,9}

> 

```css
int main()
{
    int array[TAM], num, i=0, j=0;

    printf("Ingrese arreglo: ");

    for(i=0; i < TAM -1 && num != 0; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        array[i]=num;
    }

    for(i=0; array[i] != 0 ; i++)
    {
        j++;
    }

    Alternar(array, j);

    //print array
    for(i=0; i < j; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}

void Alternar(int array[], int j)
{
    int i=0, aux, pasadas=1;

    for(pasadas=1; pasadas < j; pasadas++)
    {
        for(i=0; i < j - pasadas ; i++)
        {
            if((array[i] > 0 && array[i+1] < 0))
            {
                aux = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    int aux1=j;

    for(i=0, j; i<aux; i++, j--)
    {
        array[]=array[j];
    }


}
```

Comment: So... you want a kind of 'non-sorting' sort?

Comment: What if the counts of positive and negative numbers are different by more than one?

Comment: First, I have to sort negatives on one side and positives on the other one of the array. But then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Put all the +ve nums in one list, the negs in another.  Do an 'actual, real' sort on the +ves, then merge alternately.

Comment: It looks to me, from the example data provided, that the order of all positive numbers should not change, neither should the order of all negative numbers.  So the bubble operation should simply shuffle values down the line until a number is found that fulfills the requirement at that position.

Comment: Then, it should print {-1,3,-2,3,-4,5,6,7,8,3} (if positives > negatives} or the other way round.

Comment: This is a confusing requirement.  It may have been better if you had not used the word 'sort' at all.

Comment: My english suc ks . I am from Argentina! Thank you Martin James for the help, I will try to do two lists and merge them!

Comment: @MarcosMG No.  Your English is very good.  It's your code that sucks :)

Comment: My Spanish sucks even more than your code.   I can say 'large beer' and point at menu items in restaurants:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Alternar(int array[], int n){//`array` does not include the 0
    int i, j, k, sign;
    sign = (array[0] > 0);//Decide `sign` by the sign of first element.
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i, sign = !sign){
        if(sign == 1 && array[i] > 0 || sign == 0 && array[i] < 0)
            continue;
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
            if(sign == 1 && array[j] > 0 || sign == 0 && array[j] < 0)//find
                break;
        }
        if(j == n)//not find
            break;//return ;
        k = array[j];//save
        memmove(&array[i+1], &array[i], sizeof(int)*(j-i));//shift right
        array[i] = k;//replace
    }
}

int main(void){
    int array[] = {1, 3, -4, 5, 9, -3, -7};
    int i, n = 7;

    Alternar(array, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How much I owe you? haha. You are the king! Thank you very much! Now I get the logic behind. @BLUEPIXY